# Number of requests that can be simultaneously sent to TrueVault from an IP?

Tags: truevault

I'm writing a program to cleanup certain data from my Vaults that are irrelevant. I estimate this program to generate many thousand requests in order to completely handle all the data.

What kind of limits (either requests per second / no. of simultaneously executing requests) do I need to bake into my code?

Comment: Share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm still in the process of finishing my code, and I need to know authoritatively about these limits before I can start executing/sharing it.

Comment: @pardonmemiss: Go ahead and submit a question on TrueVault's Community Forum (https://discuss.truevault.com/) and we'll reach out to provide specific stats for you.

Comment: @Jason https://discuss.truevault.com/t/number-of-requests-that-can-be-simultaneously-sent-to-truevault-from-an-ip/44?u=aditya_menon